# Hystrix CircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, junit, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I am testing Hystrix CircuitBreaker implementation. This is how command class looks like:

```
public class CommandOne extends HystrixCommand<String>
{
    private MyExternalService service;    
    public static int runCount = 0;

    public CommandGetPunterUnpayoutExternalBets(MyExternalServoce service)
    {
        super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("AAA"))
                .andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(
                        HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter().
                         .withMetricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds(10000))
                .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                        .withCircuitBreakerEnabled(true)
                        .withCircuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage(20)
                        .withCircuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold(10)
                        .withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(30)
                        .withCircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds(100000)));

        this.service = service;
    }


    @Override
    protected String run()
    {
        run++;
        return service.callMethod();
    }


    @Override
    protected String getFallback()
    {
        return "default;
    }
}
```

Command is called like this:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private MyExternalServoce service; 

    public String callCmd()
    {
        CommandOne command = new CommandOne(service);
        return command.execute();
    }
}
```

In test I perform next steps:

```
@Test
    public void test()
{
    AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass();

    // stubbing exception on my service
    when(service.callMethod()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
             anotherClass.callCmd();
        }
    System.out.println("Run method was called times = " + CommandOne.runCount);
}
```

What I expect with the configuration of command given: MyExternalService.callMethod() should be called 10 times (RequestVolumeThreshold) and after that not being called 100000 ms (long time). In my test case I expect that CommandOne.runCount = 10. 
But in reality I am getting  from 150 to 200 calls of MyExternalService.callMethod() (CommandOne.runCount = (150-200). Why does it happening? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Hystrix [docs](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#metricshealthsnapshotintervalinmilliseconds) health snapshot will be taken once per 500ms ( by default ). Which means that everything what happens with hystrix during first 500ms will not affect circuit breaker status. In your example you got random value of `runCount` because each time your machine executed random value of requests per 500 ms, and only after that time interval circuit state was updated and closed.

Please take a look on a bit simplified example:

```
 public class CommandOne extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private String content;
    public static int runCount = 0;


    public CommandOne(String s) {
        super(Setter.withGroupKey
                (HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("SnapshotIntervalTest"))
                .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(
                        HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                                .withCircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds(500000)
                                .withCircuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold(9)
                                .withMetricsHealthSnapshotIntervalInMilliseconds(50)
                                .withMetricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds(100000)
                )
        );
        this.content = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String run() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        runCount++;
        if ("".equals(content)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFallback() {
        return "FAILURE-" + content;
    }

}

    @Test
    void test() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            CommandOne commandOne = new CommandOne();
            commandOne.execute();
        }
        Assertions.assertEquals(10, CommandOne.runCount);
    }
```

In this example I've added:

- `withMetricsHealthSnapshotIntervalInMilliseconds(50)` to allow hystrix to take snapshots each 50ms.
- `Thread.sleep(100);` to make requests a bit slower, without it they will be faster then 50 ms and we will face initial issue.

Despite of all these modifications I've seen some random failures. After this I came to conclusion that testing hystrix like this is not a good idea. Instead of it we could use:

1) [Fallback/Success flow behavior by manually setting open/close circuit state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039360/any-samples-to-unit-test-fallback-using-hystrix-spring-cloud#answer-39378236).

2) [Configuration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781398/test-drive-hystrix-circuit-breaker-configuration)