# rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds vs healthSnapshot.intervalInMilliseconds in Hystrix

Tags: java, hystrix

We are integrating Hystrix for our application. We are looking for the difference among following properties. Can someone please help?
hystrix.command.default.metrics.healthSnapshot.intervalInMilliseconds=500
vs
hystrix.command.default.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds=600000

Comment: Refer this answer here [Hystrix CircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49713391)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hystrix CircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692024/hystrix-circuitbreakersleepwindowinmilliseconds-doesnt-work-as-expected)